# NoClassDefFoundError during conversion from csv to excel

Tags: java, excel, csv

I'm getting this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException  at
>   com.restcalls.JSONtoCSV.main(JSONtoCSV.java:176)

when i'm trying to convert a `csv` file to an `excel` file.
This line seems to be causing the issue - `XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();`.

I've already added the latest POI `jar` - 3.17, this is my code:

```
String xlsxFileAddress = "C:/Users/xxxxx/REST/exports/test.xlsx"; //xlsx file address
System.out.println("here 0");
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
System.out.println("here 0.1");
XSSFSheet sheet =  workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
System.out.println("here 1");
String currentLine=null;
int RowNum=0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileAddress));
System.out.println("here 2: "+br);
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String str[] = currentLine.split(",");
    RowNum++;
    XSSFRow currentRow=sheet.createRow(RowNum);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
    }
}

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(xlsxFileAddress);
workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.5.0 is the first find when you search the maven dependency for the class.

Comment: @chillworld thanks! i added the xmlbeans-2.5.0 jar and also the poi-ooxml-schemas jar, but now i'm getting the below exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
 at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook$Factory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:248)

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml => just go to google, copy your class to google search and add mvn. Normally (exceptions exists) you will get the correct dependency in maven, just choose right version

Comment: but I'm thinking your not using maven at this moment :)

Comment: @chillworld thanks for pointing out that page, i missed the poi-ooxml-3.17.jar! I'm not getting the previous exception now. I'm having an issue with this line - workBook.write(fileOutputStream); Getting the exception _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;)V_

Comment: version conflicts, maven would really help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downlaod and add the XML beans dependency to your class path. The library is usually called xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar. For example: Search and download xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar or if you have a maven project set POM as below

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not doing a Maven project, it is a simple java project. Do i need to convert it to a Maven project?

Comment: No you don't need to convert it to to a Maven project. Just download the jar and add it to your class path.

Comment: Thanks! i've already added the 2.5.0 jar, did not get that exception anymore

Comment: When I look at dependency tree's of POI, It's easier to convert then to manually download and install all the dependencies. But as @Eritrean says, you don't have to.

Comment: @chillworld thanks! I guess there was a conflict between the jar files, so i created a clean project (was intending to create a new maven project) with only poi-3.17-beta1, poi-ooxml-3.17, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17-beta1, xmlbeans-2.5.0, commons-codec-1.10, commons-collections4-4.1, and it works now.